# ¿Como desviar Log a textView en threads no UI para Android?

Tags: java, android

Quiero que mi app imprima el log en un TextView. He creado una clase llamada Log que imita a Utils.Log, pero el problema se produce cuando se llama desde un thread diferente a UI.

Así luce la clase:

```
public class Log {

    private static Logger logger = new DefaultLogger();

    public static void l(String tag, String content) {
        logger.l(tag, content);
    }

    public static void e(String tag, String content) {
        logger.e(tag, content);
    }

    public static void setLogger(Logger l) {
        if (l != null)
            logger = l;
    }

    public interface Logger {
        void l(String tag, String content);

        void e(String tag, String content);
    }

    private static class DefaultLogger implements Logger {

        @Override
        public void l(String tag, String content) {
            android.util.Log.d(tag, content);
        }

        @Override
        public void e(String tag, String content) {
            android.util.Log.e(tag, content);
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces puedo enviar cualquier Log a un text view de la siguiente forma:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Log.Logger {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.setLogger(this);
        Log.l("Default", "El log funciona!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void l(String tag, String content) {
        // escribir log en textview aqui
        textview.append("\n" + content);
    }

    @Override
    public void e(String tag, String content) {
        // escribir log en textview aqui
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando llamo a `Log` desde un hilo que no sea Ui (como por ejemplo el thread de networking), me lanza la excepción:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: NsdManager
>   Process: com.example.app, PID: 21189
>   **android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:** 
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Para Arreglar esto he hecho:

```
@Override
public void l(final String tag, final String content) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addChatLine(tag + " * " + content);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void e(final String tag, final String content) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addChatLine(tag + " * " + content);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero no se me ocurre ninguna solución mas limpia. Me preguntaba ¿hay una solución mas "limpia" de hacer lo que quiero?

Answer (score 0):

La opción en este caso es usar [runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) para poder realizar la modificación de las propiedades de la vista en el `Thread` principal.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                 // escribir log en textview aqui
                textview.append("\n" + content);
        }
    });
```